# How to echo data from a Multi-Dimensional Array in PHP?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I need to echo/return the data to the page like this:

**Catalog:** 251-2010
**Gauge:** 20g
**Length:** 10cm
**Tip Size:** 10mm

Here is the array called $vararray. It contains several different arrays of product variation data:

```
array(3) { 
    [0]=> array(1) { 
        ["251-2010"]=> array(1) { 
            ["Gauge"]=> string(3) "20g" 
        } 
    } 
    [1]=> array(1) { 
        ["251-2010"]=> array(1) { 
            ["Length"]=> string(4) "10cm" 
        } 
    } 
    [2]=> array(1) { 
        ["251-2010"]=> array(1) { 
            ["Tip Size"]=> string(4) "10mm" 
        } 
    } 
}
array(3) { 
    [0]=> array(1) { 
        ["600-VR1620"]=> array(1) { 
            ["Chart Type"]=> string(14) "Shirt" 
        } 
    } 
    [1]=> array(1) { 
        ["600-VR1152"]=> array(1) { 
            ["Chart Type"]=> string(13) "Trousers" 
        } 
    } 
    [2]=> array(1) { 
        ["600-VR16211"]=> array(1) { 
            ["Chart Type"]=> string(13) "Socks" 
        } 
    } 
}
```

I need something like this:

```
$vargroup = array();

foreach ($vararray as $vitems) {

    $varmeta = array_values($vararray);

    foreach ($varmeta as $metain => $vardetails) {
  
        vargroup[$metain]['catalog'] = $vardetails['Catalog'];
        vargroup[$metain]['gauge'] = $vardetails['Gauge'];
        vargroup[$metain]['length'] = $vardetails['Length'];
        vargroup[$metain]['tipsize'] = $vardetails['Tip Size'];

    }
    $vars_profile = '';
    foreach ($vargroup as $vgrp) {
        $vars_profile .= $vgrp[catalog] . '<br>' . $vgrp[gauge] . '<br>' . $vgrp[length] . '<br>' . $vgrp[tipsize];
    }
}
return $vars_profile;
```

I'm having a lot of trouble getting it right. Here is how I need it to look:

**Catalog:** 251-2010
**Gauge:** 20g
**Length:** 10cm
**Tip Size:** 10mm
**Catalog:** 600-VR1620
**Chart Type:** Shirt
**Catalog:** 600-VR1152
**Chart Type:** Trousers
**Catalog:** 600-VR16211
**Chart Type:** Socks

Comment: You shouldn't have `return` inside the loop. That will stop the loop after the first iteration.

Comment: Everything starting with `$vars_profile = '';` shouldn't be in the first loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get all of `Catalog`, `Gauge`, `Length`, and `Tip Size` from the same `$vardetails` element, they're in different elements of the array. You need to drill into each element to get its key and value.

You can create `$vars_profile` in the loop that's processing the original array, you don't need `$vargroup`.

To show the category only once, use a variable to hold the last value. Only output the category line when this field changes.

```
$vars_profile = '';

$last_metain = null;
foreach ($vararray as $vitem) {
    foreach ($vitem as $metain => $vardetails) {
        if ($metain != $last_metain) {
            $vars_profile .= "<p>\nCatalog: $metain<br>\n";
            $last_metain = $metain;
        }
        foreach ($vardetails as $key => $value) {
            $vars_profile .= "$key: $value<br>\n";
        }
    }
}

return $vars_profile;
```

Comment: @Barmer I think this gets a step closer...thank you...but it does not produce the result I need as specified in my original question (please review again). First, the $vitems is only seeing the last item of each array. I tried using $vararray as $vkeys => $vitems instead but $vitems in a var_dump produced only the last item as well. Aside from the minor syntax issues, this code ($vars_profile = "$key: $value</br>";) does not give me the ability to assign a variable to each $key and each $value, which is needed, I think to display what I need.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to write `.=` for all the assignments to `$vars_profile`

Comment: I updated the display of the result I need to include all data from all arrays, so the logic of how I need it to work is clearer. I've been working on this for hours now, and need an epiphany!

Comment: Shouldn't the second and third `VR1620` be `VR1152` and `VR16211`?

Comment: Can you use `var_export($vararray)` so I can paste it into code?

Comment: Yes...they should be the numbers...I corrected the example.

Comment: array ( 0 => array ( '251-2010' => array ( 'Color' => 'Red', ), ), 1 => array ( '251-2010' => array ( 'Length' => '24in', ), ), 2 => array ( '251-2010' => array ( 'Size' => '16', ), ), )array ( 0 => array ( '600-VR1620' => array ( 'Type' => 'Shirt', ), ), 1 => array ( '600-VR1152' => array ( 'Type' => 'Trousers', ), ), 2 => array ( '600-VR16211' => array ( 'Type' => 'Socks', ), ), )

Comment: That's not a single array, that's two arrays.

Comment: Yes, it is two arrays because each one represents a product. If it helps, here is the original database query var_export():

Comment: array ( 0 => (object) array( 'cat_id' => '251-2010', 'att_name' => 'Color', 'var_value' => 'Red', ), 1 => (object) array( 'cat_id' => '251-2010', 'att_name' => 'Length', 'var_value' => '24in', ), 2 => (object) array( 'cat_id' => '251-2010', 'att_name' => 'Size', 'var_value' => '16', ), )array ( 0 => (object) array( 'cat_id' => '600-VR1620', 'att_name' => 'Type', 'var_value' => 'Shirt', ), 1 => (object) array( 'cat_id' => '600-VR1152', 'att_name' => 'Type', 'var_value' => 'Trousers', ), 2 => (object) array( 'cat_id' => '600-VR16211', 'att_name' => 'Type', 'var_value' => 'Socks', ), )

Comment: I then converted it to the current $vararray using the following code:

Comment: $attrib = array_column($vars_group, 'atts');
        $valu = array_column($vars_group, 'val');
        $catal = array_column($vars_group, 'catid');
        $attval = array_map(function($key, $val) {return array($key=>$val);}, $attrib, $valu);
        $vararray = array_map(function($key, $val) {return array($key=>$val);}, $catal, $attval);

Comment: I guess you call the function separately for each array.

Comment: I've updated the code and tested it.

Comment: Which var_export data did you use to represent $all_arrays when you tested?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to remove that. That was how I collected both of the arrays in the question into another array so I could process both of them.